# Connect to Mysql Database running on a computer over the internet withh public Ip address

Tags: mysql, remote-server

Can we Connect to Mysql Database running on a computer over the internet withh public Ip address. 
I have granted all previliges to enable remote access. I can access remotely over the lan. But is it possible to connect over the internet. I get following error
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my Public Ip address' (10061)

Comment: Show more details here on how you stablished your connection. Over the internet?

Comment: If you're using a ADSL router then you need to enable port forward using the router panel to allow the mysql port to be accessed. You need to set a firewall rule to allow incoming/outgoing connections to that specific port too. If you have a dynamic IP address then you should consider how to get the assigned IP address each time.

Comment: I am using ADSL Router to connect to internet. But i have two systems connected to internet trough the ADSL router both have mysql running on the 3306 port. how can i indentify each system. .. sory iam new to networking. thanks in advance